# Add a column to a data. frame which evenly assign rows to values in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a data frame where each row is a household, and I have a list of interviewers. The purpose is to assign the interviewers to the households and each interviewer should get the same amount of households in each city. For example,

```
example <- data.frame(city = c("Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", 
                               "San Diego", "San Diego", "San Diego", "San Diego", "San Diego",
                               "Santa Barbara", "Santa Barbara", "Santa Barbara", "Santa Barbara", "Santa Barbara"), 
                      household_id = seq(1, 13))
interviewer <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

All 3 interviewers will go to all cities and will interview about 1/3 of the households in each city, so the expected output is

```
output <- data.frame(city = c("Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", 
                               "San Diego", "San Diego", "San Diego", "San Diego", "San Diego",
                               "Santa Barbara", "Santa Barbara", "Santa Barbara", "Santa Barbara", "Santa Barbara"), 
                      household_id = seq(1, 13),
                     interviewer = c("A", "B", "C",
                                     "A", "A", "B", "B", "C",
                                     "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `rep` to repeat the `interviewer` for each `city`.

```
library(dplyr)

example %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(interviewer = rep(interviewer, length.out = n()))

#   city          household_id interviewer
#   <chr>                <int> <chr>      
# 1 Los Angeles              1 A          
# 2 Los Angeles              2 B          
# 3 Los Angeles              3 C          
# 4 San Diego                4 A          
# 5 San Diego                5 B          
# 6 San Diego                6 C          
# 7 San Diego                7 A          
# 8 San Diego                8 B          
# 9 Santa Barbara            9 A          
#10 Santa Barbara           10 B          
#11 Santa Barbara           11 C          
#12 Santa Barbara           12 A          
#13 Santa Barbara           13 B
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so elegant! I. didn't know there is a length.out argument.